# How to rename column 5 through column 66 as x1:x62 with dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, multiple-columns

How to rename column 5 through column 66 as x1:x62 with `dplyr`? Old names are arbitrary and without a pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `rename_with`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    rename_with(~ str_c("x", seq_along(.x)), 5:66)
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R:

```r
colnames(df1[5:66]) <- paste0("x", 1:62)
```

With `dplyr` syntax:

```r
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  `colnames<-`(c(colnames(df1[1:5]), paste0("x", 1:62), colnames(df1[68:ncol(df1)])))
```